# How to get next records `bending` by order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Let say I have a model Product with columns `id` and `sort_number`.

```
id      | sort_number (random)
1       | 325
2       | 161
3       | 58
...
147     | 500 # the biggest sort_number number is equal to the Product.count result
...
500     | 5
```

I want a `next(n = 20)` and `previous(n = 20)` methods for the Product instances. IE if I:

```
product = Product.find(43)
product.sort_number # => 490
product.next(20) # should return products with sort_number equal to (491..500) + (1..10)
```

How can I implement this functionality? How can I get the next record with sort_number started at 1, if there are no more records next?

Comment: `Product.where 'sort_number > ? AND sort_number < ?', product.sort_number, product.sort_number + 20`

Comment: What will be if `sort_number` equal to 100? I will need to get records with `101-120` sort_number

Comment: You’ll get them. For `(490..500)` and `(1..10)` you’ll need another query basing on returned count. I am not aware of 1-query method to achieve that (in fact, I am, but the SQL query will be unreadable.)

Comment: Can you write me 2-query method, please?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I will put this as an answer.

```
def next id, count 
  product = Product.find(id)
  products = Product.where(
                'sort_number > ? AND sort_number <= ?',
                product.sort_number, product.sort_number + count
             ) # this will return 20 requested, unless sort_number is near 500

  products |= Product.where(
                'sort_number > 1 AND sort_number <= ?',
                count - product.count
             ) if products.count < count

  products
end
```